# assign default value to a jackson field of type JsonNode

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I have a following DTO class in Spring with a JsonNode field as shown below

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

@lombok.Data
class ABC {
    @JsonProperty("info")
    JsonNode info;
}
```

Is there a more concise way to assign default value to the field than the one mentioned below so that accessing abcObj.getInfo().toString() always gives "{}" if info is null? I have at least 5 such fields and I want to avoid duplicating this code.

```
public JsonNode getInfo() {
        if (this.info == null) {
            return JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
        }
        return this.info;
    }
```

Another way that I could think of is define a static method in a Constants class that always returns an empty json node and use it to initialize while declaring the member data.

```
@JsonProperty("info")
private JsonNode info = Constants.getEmptyJsonNode();
```

But this way, I need to create separate methods for fields of different types like List, JsonNode etc.

I tried using defaultValue option in [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) too but it doesn't seem to provide the functionality I am looking for.

Comment: Why does your DTO contain `JsonNode` directly?  Shouldn't the DTO have the actual datatype like a `List`?  Seems like this is a code smell, but maybe I don't know the pattern.

Comment: The DTO is for an external third party API response, some of whose fields are complex JSONs themselves. We have used JSON node to make our code resilient to changes in the structure of these fields.

Comment: Gotcha.  I poked around a bit and I think your `Constants.getEmptyJsonNode()` is the best approach.